# Google ML Engine - How to properly terminate a Datalab session

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I tried to follow this guide using the Cloud Shell:
https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/quickstarts/datalab, but when I was
going to stop my session I couldn't avoid getting an error.

Everything works fine until the clean up part. Then I close the Datalab
browser tab and press `CTRL + C` in the Cloud Shell. This error is reported
in the Cloud Shell:

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 3] No such process`.

Then I press CTRL + C again and get back to the prompt from where I can
call

`datalab stop <instance-name>`

Later it works to connect again by calling
`datlab connect <instance-name>`

Could someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here? How can I properly
terminate the Datalab session without producing an error?

**UPDATE:**

After some trial and error I found out that one should not consider using `CTRL + Z` followed by something like `bg`, `ps -e`, `kill <pid>` where pid is the process id for the datalab process. Because there are several processes involved and killing only the datalab process will leave the Cloud Shell crippled. One will then have to restart the Cloud Shell VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a recent issue with the latest versions of the Cloud SDK.

I've created [this issue](https://github.com/googledatalab/datalab/issues/1381) to track it.

However, in the meantime the way you are terminating the session is the one you want to use; it will just generate spurious error messages that you can ignore.